# Functions and cycle notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

Let $g=(1 6 9 3 10 8 7)(2)(4 5)$ and $h(g)=(1 8 10 2 7 3 6 4)$. Find $h$.

I realised that $h=h(g(g^{-1}))$ and so I found $g^{-1}=(1 7 8 10 3 9 6)(2)(4 5)$. But when finding $h$, I found some elements which don't exist in $h(g)$. Is what I have done, correct so far? How can it be finished?

Comment: What do you mean by "elements that don't exist in h(g)"?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you need to find $g^{-1}$. You can then use this cycle to solve for $h$, as we have the equation $hg = (\text{1 8 10 2 7 3 6 4})$. We then right multiply by $g^{-1}$, so $h = (\text{1 8 10 2 7 3 6 4}) \circ (\text{1 7 8 10 3 9 6})(\text{2})(\text{4 5})$, which we can simplify to $(\text{1 3 9 4 5})(\text{2 7 10 6 8})$. You can check that this is the correct cycle.

If you are familiar with the language of groups, we are just doing the usual group operations in $S_n$.